# Intel Corporation Raptor Lake-P/U/H cAVS (rev 01) Wired audio connection not working

Tags: sound, hp

```
lspci
 00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Raptor Lake-P/U/H cAVS (rev 01)
```

The inbuilt speaker output working fine. But the audio jack is not detected.
My laptop is hp 15-hr0001TU

Comment: same problem, any update?